# UIScrollView not scrolling to bottom of view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a weird bug that I am currently facing. In my storyboard, I toggled my navigation controller auto layout switch to the checked ON position. I then toggled it OFF, expecting no issues.

I then proceeded to change the view controller size to 3.5 inches, which I quickly toggled back to the 4 inch screen size(original size).

After doing these mindless tasks, I run my app. **There were no issues prior to performing those two tasks, but now my scroll views will not scroll down to the bottom of their individual views! I have disabled auto layout but it seems as though it has affected my project. Any ideas? I am running the new Xcode 6 beta.**

Comment: Is the content view of the scroll view the expected size?

Comment: @bdev I did an NSLog and my view is only 568px high! However, I have the view's height set to 750px. Any ideas? The scrollview is the correct size, as is the contentview which is on top of the scrollview. Keep in mind I did not touch any code to cause this bug. Thanks!

Comment: I set the size of the view using interface builder. I selected "freeform", and set its size to 320x750. This worked perfectly until I toggled the two switches.

Comment: I ended up just having to roll back to an older version of my app before I toggled the switches. I would still love to know what happened though.